# Where to add magic numbers in my project?

Tags: java, design-patterns, constants, magic-numbers

I have a lot of magic numbers and strings in my project and I would like to replace them with constants. The thing is I remember I used, a lot of time ago, a class to hold all the constants that I would call in the code statically. It is a university project and I need to use Java design patterns.

I would like to know what's the best way to write the constants given the fact that many magic numbers are used across different classes, so I don't want to declare constants locally in each class.

I've read about resource files implemented via singleton classes, but I can't figure out why using a singleton class that makes calls to it longer than needed.

I'm writing code in Java for the server and Android for the client in case you need this info.

Comment: this is more a matter of opinion and convention within your circle, rather than a question with a definite solution. some might choose to provide an entire class of finals, others would start each class with the relevant magic numbers provided

Comment: @HadarSharvit Ok thanks! And If I want to declare a class could I just create a public class with static public finals in order to access them throughout my code or there's some convention that forces me to use a certain design pattern for that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Enam or Class file for it. Every one of your packages can have some class for example it:

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
public final class Constant {

    @NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
    public static final class Date {

        public static final int Q_ONE_MONTH = 3;

        public static final int Q_TWO_MONTH = 6;

        public static final int Q_THREE_MONTH = 9;

        public static final int Q_FOUR_MONTH = 12;
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
    public static final class Quarter {

        public static final int Q_ONE = 1;

        public static final int Q_TWO = 2;

        public static final int Q_THREE = 3;

        public static final int Q_FOUR = 4;
    }
}
```

These classes can be in each of your packages for everyone on their own or one class in a common project module.

Comment: I'd avoid using Lombok annotations in answers that are unrelated to Lombok. It's far from universally used and might confuse many.

Comment: do it without lombok. I show common idea

Comment: Okay, you gave me the idea of what I can do, thank you so much!